# using multiple baseUrl's when building with require.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, r.js

I have a project with a structure that looks similar to this:

```
/path/to/project
    /apps
        /app1
            /js
                /modules
                    /bar.js
                    /etc..
                /app1.js
                /app1.build.js
        /foo
            /app2
                /js
                    /modules
                        /cad.js
                        /etc..
                    /app2.js
                    /app2.build.js
    /static
        /js
            /libraries
                /jQuery
                /etc...
            /common-config.js
            /common-build-config.js
```

`common-config.js` defines a set of paths for loading libraries that is relative to the web-root of the project that both `app1` and `app2` can use.  The goal of `common-build-config.js` is to provide similar functionality for the build process.  The problem I am encountering is that I cannot use fully-qualified paths in `common-build-config.js`, as `path/to/project` is dependent on a number of factors (environment, project branch, server, etc), and relative paths fail because the relative paths from `app1` and `app2` to `common-build-config.js` are different.  Module loading in `app1` and `app2` assumes that the base directory is the app directory, so I cannot change the `baseUrl` parameter in the `app[x].build.js` files without manually specifying paths for a ton of modules.

Is there a way I can specify `baseUrl` in `common-build-config.js` such that it will not affect the path loading in either of the `main.build.js` files?  Alternatively, is there a way to use variables when defining paths in the build config (like getting the value of Node's `__dirName` variable)?  Or is there another approach that can end-route this problem?

Example files:

**[/path/to/project/static/common-config.js]**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '/static/js/libraries/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: '/static/js/libraries/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '/static/js/libraries/backbone/backbone'
    }
});
```

**[/path/to/project/apps/app1/js/app1.js]**

```
require(['/static/js/common-config.js'], function () {
    require([
        // Load common modules
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        // Load local modules
        'bar'
    ], function ($, _, backbone, bar) {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

**[/path/to/project/apps/app1/js/app1.build.js]**

```
({
    name: 'app1',
    out: './app1.min.js',
    optimize: 'uglify',
    mainConfigFile: '../../../../static/js/common-build-config.js',
    findNestedDependencies: true
})
```

**[/path/to/project/static/common-build-config.js]**

It would be nice if I could do something like this without affecting the paths in app1.build.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libraries/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: 'libraries/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: 'libraries/backbone/backbone'
    }
});
```

or something like this without getting an error like `__dirName is not defined`:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: __dirName + 'libraries/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: __dirName + 'libraries/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: __dirName + 'libraries/backbone/backbone'
    }
});
```

In case it's relevant, I build the min files from the project root with the commands:

```
node "static/js/libraries/require/r.js" -o "apps/app1/js/app1.build.js"
node "static/js/libraries/require/r.js" -o "apps/foo/app2/js/app2.build.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution to this in require.js, but I wrote a nAnt script that does a string replace on the config script before running the build, which end-routes the problem:

```
<target name="build.require.common">
    <!-- copy the common build config file to a temp file -->
    <copy file="static/js/common-build-config-template.js" tofile="static/js/common-build-config.js" overwrite="true">
        <filterchain>
            <!-- replace {root} with the project root directory (defined elsewhere) -->
            <replacestring from="{root}" to="${projectRoot}" />
        </filterchain>
    </copy>

    <!-- run node "static/js/r.js" -o "apps/app1/js/app1.build.js" -->
    <exec program="${nodeExe}">
        <arg line="&quot;static/js/r.js&quot; -o &quot;apps/app1/js/app1.build.js&quot;"/>
    </exec>

    <!-- delete the temp config file -->
    <delete file="static/js/common-build-config.js" />
</target>
```

with a `common-build-config-template.js` file that looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '{root}/libraries/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: '{root}/libraries/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '{root}/libraries/backbone/backbone'
    }
});
```